# How to get return value from coroutine in python

Tags: python, generator, coroutine

I'm trying coroutines pipeline according to http://www.dabeaz.com/coroutines/Coroutines.pdf

The question is, how can I get value from the `sink` rather than only print it?

Take this code for example

```
def coroutine(func):
    def start(*args, **kwargs):
        cr = func(*args, **kwargs)
        next(cr)
        return cr
    return start


@coroutine
def produce(target):
    while True:
        n = (yield)
        target.send(n*10)


@coroutine
def sink():
    try:
        while True:
            n = (yield)
            print(n)
    except GeneratorExit:
        pass


sk = sink()
pipe = produce(sink())
```

With this code I get:

```
>>> pipe.send(10)
100
```

Then I want to get the return value rather than print it, I try to yield from sink:

```
@coroutine
def sink():
    try:
        while True:
            yield (yield)
    except GeneratorExit:
        pass
```

But it seems not working, `pipe.send(10)` still returns `None` rather than a generator.

So how shall I get the return value?

Answer (score 3):

Why should `pipe.send` return a generator? And what are you going to do with the returned value?

Whatever it is, it should be done in `sink`.

You could, however, change your functions to

```
@coroutine
def produce(target):
    while True:
        n = (yield)
        yield target.send(n*10)

@coroutine
def sink():
    try:
        while True:
            yield (yield)
    except GeneratorExit:
        pass
```

to yield the value yielded by `target`, so `pipe.send(10)` will just return `100` instead of printing it.

But now you mix the producer and the consumer, which will potentially give you some headache.

---

In response to your comment:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def coroutine(func):
    def start(*args, **kwargs):
        cr = func(*args, **kwargs)
        next(cr)
        return cr
    return start

@coroutine
def produce(key, target):
    while True:
        n = (yield)
        target.send((key, n*10))

class Sink(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.d = defaultdict(lambda: None)
        self.co = self.sink()

    def send(self, *args):
        self.co.send(*args)

    @coroutine
    def sink(self):
        try:
            while True:
                key, n = yield
                self.d[key] = max(self.d[key], n)
        except GeneratorExit:
            pass


sk = Sink()
pipeA = produce("A", sk)
pipeB = produce("B", sk)

pipeA.send(10)
pipeA.send(20)
pipeA.send(40)

pipeB.send(20)
pipeB.send(40)
pipeB.send(60)

print sk.d.items() # [('A', 400), ('B', 600)]
```

Comment: Say if I push in value A and value B, after filter, broadcasting, processing etc, A generated 10 values to sink, and B generated 8 values to sink. And I want the max value from A and max value from B, but how shall I tell which value generated from A or from B? Any idea on how to do it in sink?

Comment: @lxyu You can send in a key to know which producer produced a value, and the sink could have a state to know which values where send in and which value is the max value. See my edit.

Comment: I suggest sending an object that encapsulates all the data that you need!